# Edición de datos en formulario de Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

Hola tengo el siguiente comportamiento y no se como resolverlo tengo 2 componentes un `user` y un `editar-usuario`. En el primer componente tengo la siguiente tabla[image: ``]

```
<div *ngIf="!crearEditar" class="container">
    <mat-toolbar>
        <span>Usuarios</span>
        <div class="example-spacer"></div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="crearEditar = !crearEditar" routerLink="/dashboard/editar-usuario">Agregar</button>
      </mat-toolbar>
      <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
      <div>
    <div *ngIf="!loading">
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
            <mat-label>Filtrar Usuarios</mat-label>
            <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" #input autocomplete="off">
          </mat-form-field>
          <div  class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>            
                <!-- Position Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="usuario">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Usuario </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.usuario}} </td>
                </ng-container>
                <!-- Name Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Nombre </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.nombre}} </td>
                </ng-container>
              
                <!-- Weight Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="apellido">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Apellido </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.apellido}} </td>
                </ng-container>
              
                <!-- Symbol Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="dni">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DNI </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dni}} </td>
                </ng-container>
        
                  <!-- Symbol Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="acciones">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>  </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" style="text-align:right;"> 
                        <a class="pointer" style="color:#1878b0" matTooltip="Ver Usuario"><mat-icon>search</mat-icon></a>
                        <a class="pointer" style="color:#0aac2d" matTooltip="Editar Usuario" routerLink="/dashboard/editar-usuario" (click)="editarUsuario(element.idUsuario)"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></a>
                        <a class="pointer" style="color:#cf1c1c" matTooltip="Eliminar Usuario" (click)="eliminarUsuario(element.idUsuario)"><mat-icon>delete</mat-icon></a>
                    </td>
                  </ng-container>
              
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
              </table>
              <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements"></mat-paginator>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y en el segundo componente tengo el siguiente formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="container">
    <mat-toolbar>
        <span>Crear Usuario</span>
      </mat-toolbar>
      <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading" diameter="50" class="spinner"></mat-spinner>
    <form  [formGroup]="form" >
        <mat-grid-list cols="10" rowHeight="60px">
            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
                <label class="margen-label">Usuario</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ancho" formControlName="usuario" id="usuario">
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="4" [rowspan]="4">
                <img src="../../../../assets/images/icon-alta-usuario.png" width="150" height="150"alt="">
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
                <label class="margen-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ancho" formControlName="nombre" id="nombre">
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
                <label class="margen-label">Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control ancho" formControlName="apellido" id="apellido">
            </mat-grid-tile>
            <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
                <label class="margen-label">DNI</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control margen-text-input-dni" formControlName="dni" id="dni">
            </mat-grid-tile>
          </mat-grid-list>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div class="row" *ngIf="!loading">
        <div class="form-group pl-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateUsuarios($event)" [disabled]="form.invalid" routerLink="/dashboard/users">Agregar</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group pl-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" routerLink="/dashboard/users">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Formulario que se muestra tanto ingresando por el botón Agregar por medio de un `routerLink`, como también utilizando el botón Editar de cada uno de los `items`.
Al presionar el botón editar se ejecuta un método que se encuentra en el `user.component`

```
editarUsuario(id: number) {
    this.route.editarUsuarios(id);
  }
```

al cual le paso el id del del `item`. Este método llama a otro método que se encuentra en el segundo componente dentro del `editar-usuario.component`

```
editUsuarios(id: number) {
this._usuarioService.getUsuario(id).subscribe(data =>{
        this.form.setValue({
          'usuario': this.datosUsuario.usuario,
          'nombre': this.datosUsuario.nombre,
          'apellido': this.datosUsuario.apellido,
          'dni': this.datosUsuario.dni,
        })
}
```

al cual hasta ahí le llega el valor del id del `item`. Y acá es donde se me comienza a complicar la situación, dado que no logro dentro de este método encontrar la forma de setearle los valores del `user` al formulario. Cosa que si logro desde el método `ngOnInit` harcodeandole el valor (18) de `id` ya que si intento utilizar el mismo `id` obtenido en el `user` me lo toma como `undefined`. Este es el código utilizado para setearle los valores al formulario desde el `ngOnInit`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this._usuarioService.getUsuario(18).subscribe(data =>{
          this.form.setValue({
            'usuario': this.datosUsuario.usuario,
            'nombre': this.datosUsuario.nombre,
            'apellido': this.datosUsuario.apellido,
            'dni': this.datosUsuario.dni,
          })
        }) 
}
```

La pregunta sería como puedo hacer para que al método `ngOnInit` le llegue ese `id` (sin utilizar `@input` que tampoco me funciona) o como puedo hacer que desde el método `editUsuarios` se complete el `formulario`.
El formulario se encuentra definido en el `editar-usuario.component` de la siguiente forma.

```
form = new FormGroup({
    usuario: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    nombre: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    apellido: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    dni: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
```

Si utilizo el `var id = this.activeRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');` me trae los datos correctamente pero me muestra el `editar-usuario.html` por fuera de mi `dashboar`.
En vez de ver de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Se ve solo esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `Objeto` `datosUsuarios` se setea en el  editar-usuario.component como `datosUsuario: Usuario;` donde el `Usuario` esta definido como un `Model`

```
export class Usuario {
    usuario: String;
    dni: number;
    nombre: string;
    apellido: string;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener el id desde la ruta, agrega esto a tu constructor:
`private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute`  y en el ngOnInit haces esto:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 var id = this.activeRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
 this._usuarioService.getUsuario(id).subscribe(data =>{
          this.form.setValue({
            'usuario': this.datosUsuario.usuario,
            'nombre': this.datosUsuario.nombre,
            'apellido': this.datosUsuario.apellido,
            'dni': this.datosUsuario.dni,
          })
        }) 
}
```

Otra forma de obtener el id de la ruta es:

```
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute){
 this.id = activeRoute.params
        .pipe(pluck('id'));
}
```

Comment: Perdón no había notado que copie el código con un error, ahí lo volví a editar y ese no es el inconveniente dado q ese `id` si trae el valor correspondiente

Comment: Edité la repuesta, léela de nuevo y verifica si te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Otra cosa donde seteas el objeto datosUsuarios?

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen?

Comment: Ahí agregue mas información a la consulta.

Comment: Edité la repuesta con otra forma de obtener el id,  es un poco extraño que no te muestra el dashboard ya que la primera solución no tiene que ver con ello. Hay que ver la estructura del routing.

Comment: Si el dashboard es el padre siempre debe mostrarse cuando se llamen los hijos.